# how do I create a macro for two-way links?

Tags: macros, hyperlink, hypertarget

I'm trying to extend a previous href command (that works) to create a pair of new commands that wrap \hyperlink{}{} and \hypertarget{}{}.

The commands would work together to create hypertargets for hyperlinks to call. (Basically, two way internal PDF links from outline to content are the desired end result - programmatically driven by my Python code )

(Filling in the parameters are no problem, already in my code.  But the syntax for the LaTeX command is throwing errors.)

Depending on whether I am in the outline, or in the actual the content, I want to make calls to the commands like so:

```tex
\linkfromout{the key text}{the document's Text} 
\linkfromcom{the key text}{The Document's text}
```

Correct capitalization may vary for what is printed in the document. But the key text for the \hyperlink and \hypertarget will be all lowercase. The macro needs to prepend `com` or `out` to make a distinction for the target location that is reached by the hyperlink call.

The code below, placed in a custom sty file, is failing for me.  I've attempted to resolve some errors with the backslash parameter, but it still fails.  Any help is appreciated.   I'm still new to LaTeX.

```tex
\newcommand{linkfromout}[2]{\hyperlink{com \#1}{\hypertarget{out \#1}{\textcolor{linkColor}{\#2}}}}

\newcommand{linkfromcom}[2]{\hyperlink{out \#1}{\hypertarget{com \#1}{\textcolor{linkColor}{\#2}}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just didn't properly escape your new commands (you need a `\` before `linkfromout` etc. in the preamble) and improperly escaped the arguments (no `\` before `#`). The following runs for me without error and is from what I can tell your expected behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, xcolor}
\newcommand{\linkfromout}[2]{\hyperlink{com #1}{\hypertarget{out #1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\linkfromcom}[2]{\hyperlink{out #1}{\hypertarget{com #1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\linkfromout{the key text}{the document's Text} 
\newpage
\linkfromcom{the key text}{The Document's text} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Dan ... that was it.  I thought I was going crazy ... now I know for sure, forgetting to backslash the command name itself. LOL